# React Native Expo - Custom fonts don't seem to work

Tags: react-native, mobile, fonts, expo

I am working on some test project to learn how to use react native with expo, but there is a problem I cannot resolve.

I want to have custom fonts, which I downloaded from google fonts and put in assets/fonts. I want to have the ability to use them globally, so there is my App.js code:

```
import { React } from 'react';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from './Login/LoginScreen';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

function App() {
  const [isLoaded] = useFonts({
    'MMedium': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf'),
    'MSemiBold': require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'Oswald': require('./assets/fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf'),
  });


  if (!isLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AppContainer />
  );
}


export default App;
```

I am assuming, that it is not working, because they are not visible in the Expo Go, which I use to see the results of code. It would be awesome, if someone helped me to find the problem!

Update: there were two reasons, why this was not working:

1. You need to add custom fonts in 'start point' of your app. Generally it is yours App.js, but I also had index.js.
2. When loading not system fonts you need to use Font.loadAsync.

That was my two problems - hope this will help someome and have a good day!